# Resize div based on td width

Tags: autosize

I'm trying to change the width of a div to be the same as the width of a table cell. Neither will be fixed widths, so also need to be able to detect when the size changes.
Trying to accomplish something like the below, but not sure how.

```
var myvalue = document.getElementsByClassName('tableCell'); 
document.getElementByClassName('test').style.width= myvalue.offsetWidth+'px';

<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><div class="test"></div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tableCell">test</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.test').width( $('.tableCell').width() );
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wpNFk/

Comment: That does not make any sense

Comment: This only works if the `div` is within the `td`, which the example in the question strongly suggests is not the case.

Comment: I misread ur code. i edited my post, but its usin jquery, since i know no 'autosize' language

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! I added a window resize function as well so that the width of the div continues to change as window size does.